# Cipher: "YB AUVQ DUUACRQ"

Tags: cipher

"YB AUVQ DUUACRQ" I've tried every rotation of Cesear and lots of frequency analysis and all I've been able to come up with is "I'm done goodbye". I'm fairly sure that if it is monoalphabetic this has to be the answer. The girl who wrote it says this isn't the answer but it's all I've found.

Comment: I'm not doubtful that she would lie about me getting it.

Comment: An online monoalphabetic cipher solver gives over 200 answers for this... some are more likely than others but without any sort of hint this will be very hard to solve...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I believe the answer is, in fact, **I'm done goodbye.** It is encrypted in the following logical order: For each letter, shift it two keys left on a standard QWERTY keyboard.